# Run VSE movie strip output through Compositor or Compositor movie clip output through VSE within one project possible?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes

I wish to add a movie clip into Blender then simultaneously use both
VSE and Compositor (nodes) to produce various video effects.
The VSE offers some nice options, and so does the Compositor.
So far, within a single Blender project, I have not been able to figure out how to either
-take the output of the VSE movie strip and then run that output through the Compositor for further processing
or
-take the output from the Compositor movie clip and run that output through the VSE for further processing.
I wish to do this all within one project file.
Is that possible?
Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a separate Compositor Scene that only outputs the compositor result. Then in the VSE scene you can add the Compositor scene as a scene strip.

You can not send the output of the VSE anywhere except for mixdown to codec. Don't worry, everyone asks this at some point.

The VSE is designed to be the end of the production chain.

Comment: Okay thanks, that does clarify things for me. I think it's also needed in the compositor scene to uncheck sequencer at properties>post processing. And at VSE scene to uncheck compositor at properties>post processing. Is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: Well, with some more testing it looks like I just leave both post processing options checked (enabled) in each scene. Not sure if there's any benefit to disabling either of those two options in any scene.

Comment: Yeah they are dependent upon output at the tool. The compositor will be ignored if theres no output node and the VSE will be ignored if there are no strips present.